# Delete a Cookie in Nuxt.js 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to make a function that deletes a cookie when a button is clicked. I'm using the `useCookie` function from Nuxt 3. Since `useCookie` is provided by `h3`, I tried using `deleteCookie` (another function from h3), but that didn't work. I also tried setting the expire date to the past:

```
useCookie('userId', {
    expires: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1)
})
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact issue, but according to `cookie-es` (the library used by Nuxt to process cookies) typings (https://github.com/unjs/cookie-es/blob/main/src/types.ts), `expires` is required to be a `Date` object.

Comment: Can you be more precise regarding `that didn't work`?

Comment: I meant that the cookie wasn't deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how useCookie works in Nuxt 3:

To get cookie:

```
const cookie = useCookie(name, options)
```

To set cookie:

```
cookie.value = YOUR_VALUE
```

To remove cookie

```
cookie.value = null
```

Answer (score 9):

**Updated Feb 2023:**

To delete a cookie in Nuxt 3, we can simply set it `null` or `undefined`:

```
<script setup>
function logout () {
   const authCookie = useCookie('auth')
   authCookie.value = null
}
<script>
```

This would automatically remove cookie because in this [link](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/blob/dc62dde299cd0dd819bceb9ceb8fc4a314f3f670/packages/nuxt/src/app/composables/cookie.ts#L56-L61) , Nuxt will set the `maxAge: -1` if the cookie is `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`deleteCookie` from h3  works for me
https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#deleteCookie

```js
deleteCookie(event, 'token', {
  httpOnly: true,
  path: '/',
  sameSite: 'strict',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set value to `null`**

You can delete the cookie by setting the cookie's value to either `null` or `undefined`. Nuxt will then override the cookie's `Max-Age` and set it to -1 before setting the cookie in the browser, effectively deleting it.

Set the cookie to `null` like this:

```
const userIdCookie = useCookie('userId')
userIdCookie = null
```

and watch it reactively disappear from the browser's cookie jar.

**How this works**

The reactive `userIdCookie` object you got from `useCookie` will serialize the cookie like this:

```
if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return serialize(name, value, { ...opts, maxAge: -1 })
}
```

and then set it client-side with `document.cookie = serializeCookie(...)` or server-side with `appendHeader(event, 'Set-Cookie', serializeCookie(...)` as per `useCookie()`'s source: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/blob/dc62dde299cd0dd819bceb9ceb8fc4a314f3f670/packages/nuxt/src/app/composables/cookie.ts#L56-L61

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Same discussion has been on the official nuxt page:
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2576

Comment: setting it to null or undefined does not remove the cookie

Comment: This should be:  'userIdCookie.value = null'